# Second connection object throwing error inside Transaction Scope

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, transactionscope

I'm developing a desktop application using VS.net and SQL Server. In one of the form, am using Transaction Scope. The code is as follows:-

//Constructor code

```
InitializeComponent();
ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConSQLServerExp"].ConnectionString;
connectionString2 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConSQLServerExp"].ConnectionString;
```

//Button save code

```
string sql1 = @"SELECT sub_id FROM TABLE1 WHERE c_id=@c_id";

try
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con1.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, con1))
            {
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@c_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = clsId;
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlDataReader rdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr1.Read())
                    {
                        string sql2 = @"INSERT INTO TABLE2(casm_cls_id,casm_ass_id,casm_subj_text,casm_subj_id,casm_subj_mm) 
                                                    VALUES(@casm_cls_id,@casm_ass_id,@casm_subj_text,@casm_subj_id,@casm_subj_mm)";
                        using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString2))
                        {
                            con2.Open();
                            using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, con2))
                            {
                                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@casm_cls_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = clsId;
                                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@casm_ass_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = assId;
                                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@casm_subj_text", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = lvMapList.Items[row].SubItems[4].Text;
                                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@casm_subj_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(rdr1["sub_id"].ToString());
                                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@casm_subj_mm", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtMaxMarks.Text.Trim());
                                cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            scope.Complete();

            MessageBox.Show("Records added", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
catch (TransactionAbortedException tex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("1-1--->>" + tex.Message);
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("1-2--->>" + ex.Message);
}
```

I'm encountering error at

```
con2.Open();
```

The error message simply says that the transaction has aborted.
Can anyone please explain what am I doing wrong or whats the correct way to do it?

Comment: My assumption is both transaction scopes are attempting to use the same port, and this it won't work... And that reading the exception more carefully would confirm this.

Comment: You are opening two connections in one scope. This inevitably means the whole transaction must be upgraded to a distributed transaction, and that usually fails on not having configured MSDTC. If you split up processing so the results of the reader are retrieved first (and stored in a list or suchlike) and then use a second loop to perform the inserts, that won't be an issue (because `TransactionScope` knows not to use a distributed transaction for an identical connection, if it's closed first). Alternatively, rewrite the whole thing as one single `INSERT ... FROM` if it's always the same DB.